# Retrieving related data from Result object

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have the following relationship on my Entry result class:

```
package Schema::Result::Entry;
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "entry_i18ns",
  "Schema::Result::EntryI18n",
  { "foreign.entry_id" => "self.id" },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

So i want to retrieve related data from a newly created Schema::Result::Entry object:

```
$result = $schema->resultset('Result')->create({ entry_i18ns => { title => 'foo', language_code => 'en' } });
```

The problem is that `entry_i18ns` accessor executes extra SELECT and returns all the related EntryI18n objects, not the specific one which was created with create() call.

As far as i can see, data i need is stored with `$result->{_relationship_data}{entry_i18ns}` array ref so i can access it whith something like

```
my $related_data = $result->{_relationship_data}{entry_i18ns}[0]{_column_data};
```

But how can i do it without messing up with internal DBIC private storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No accessor for this in DBIC. An accessors for a “multi” relationship [always do new select](http://metacpan.org/source/RIBASUSHI/DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship/Accessor.pm#L97). But you can create [own component](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Component.pod) which adds that accessor. Or just add method to the result class.